# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while fetching data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch users data from API. I am having error which is:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while fetching data

I read and check many examples what others did It seems quite easy to figure but as I am new I could not catch it out where the error comes from.

Where is my error? Why is that error appearing and what caused it?

```
import {
    LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOG_OUT,
    GETALL_REQUEST, GETALL_SUCCESS, GETALL_FAILURE
} from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export function getAllUser() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request());
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(res => console.info(res.data))
            .then(
                users => dispatch(success(users)),
                error => dispatch(failure(error))
            )
    }
    function request() {
        return { type: GETALL_REQUEST }
    }
    function success(users) {
        return {
            type: GETALL_SUCCESS,
            payload: users
        }
    }
    function failure(error) {
        return {
            type: GETALL_FAILURE,
            error
        }
    }
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllUser } from '../../actions/authenticationActions';

class Users extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getAllUser()
    }
    render() {
        console.info(`users:`, this.props.users)
        const userList = this.props.users.map(user => (
            <tr key={user.id}>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.username}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
            </tr>
        ));
        if (!userList) {
            return (
                <div>
                    Not Found...
            </div>
            )
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Username</th>
                            <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{userList}</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Users.propTypes = {
    getAllUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.info('state', state);
    return {
        users: state.users.items,
        isFetching: state.users.isFetching
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getAllUser: users => dispatch(getAllUser(users))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

```
import { GETALL_REQUEST, GETALL_SUCCESS, GETALL_FAILURE } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {},
    isFetching: true
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GETALL_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
            };
        case GETALL_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload,
                isFetching: false
            };
        case GETALL_FAILURE:
            return {}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: is this line then(res => console.info(res.data)) working for you ? are you seeing in the console the response?

Comment: Yes there are response in array

Comment: @ŞehirRehberi what is the return value for ```console.info(`users:`, this.props.users)``` within your code

Comment: example0: {id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret", email: "Sincere@april.biz", address: {…}, …}

Comment: In the `mapStateToProps` of your component you are mapping `state.users.items` to the prop `users` but in your reducer it seems that your users info is being mapped to `state.items`.
What do you see in your `console.info('state', state);`?

Comment: users:
isFetching: true
item: {}
items: []

Answer (score 0):

I have built your code into sandbox, and the issue you are facing resides inside your action. You can't perform side effects inside your actions. Redux will complain about that:

[image]

To fix it you have two options:

1. Use [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                // this.setState({ response.data });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

2. Use a middleware (e.g redux-saga, redux-thunk) for handling your side effects i.e your get requests.

Comment: when I change reducer like following code it works; export const getAllUser = () => dispatch => { axios.get('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') .then(res => res.data) .then(users => dispatch({ type: GETALL_SUCCESS, payload: users, }) ) .catch(error => { console.error(error) }) };

Answer (score 0):

`console.info` returns undefined, so you don't pass your array to success handler, but undefined

Use

```
.then(res => res.data)
```

or

```
.then(res => {console.info(res.data); return res.data;})
```

See the difference in following example:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve){
  resolve([1,2,3]);
});

promise.then(res=>{console.info("1 step",res); return res}) //return array
       .then(res=>console.info("2 step", res)) //only log
       .then(res=>console.info("3 step", res)) //ups... res is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(res => dispatch(success(res)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(failure(error)))
```

I think there is no data key in the response! that's why you get that error!